# Changing the JAXB namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a legacy system to which we send data which is hardcoded to demand a specific XML namespace be used.  They have published the XSD and I'm generating JAXB classes from it.  But when I run the code, my XML comes out like this:

```
<ns3:field1>data</ns3:field1>
```

But the legacy system requires:

```
<custom:field1>data</custom:field1>
```

JAXB is generating 100% legal XML, but the legacy system cannot handle the namespace being different.

**I cannot change the legacy system or the XSD.**

Is there any better way to make the resulting XML come out the way I need besides doing String.replace("ns3:", "custom:")?  I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Yes. You can use `XmlFilterImpl' Today only I used to ignore the namespace answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637547/how-do-i-parse-xml-content-that-may-or-may-not-have-a-namespace/46639524#46639524 You can modify the namespace as per your requirement. Get more details on it.

Comment: It seems like question is not about namespace but about its prefix. If it is, I guess that link http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html may help you

Answer (score 2):

Write package-info.java -

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://your-namespace-url",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {
            @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://your-namespace-url"),
            @XmlNs(prefix = "custom", namespaceURI = "http://your-namespace-url/other")
    })
```

As you don't define package-info, that's why it put that namespace prefix.

Comment: The problem with this solution is many people use a task to auto-generate the xml artifacts and thus, any package-info.java file would have to go into an auto-generated directory that could get wiped out at any time. I wish the API designers had considered this